# How can I convert a characters into dates in RStudio?

Tags: r, datetime, command, rstudio, bar-chart

still new to R. I wanted to create a simple (bar) chart of the fluctuations/occurrences of burglaries per month in my city. I found that the column, 'Occurence_Date' is a character, I wanted it to be "time", or something simpler, to create a visualization. I wanted the "x-axis" to be the months of January to June  2019, with the "y-axis" to be the amount of burglaries per month. Can anyone help me get started on this please? Thanks!

[This is my data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr6qn.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please post a sample of your data using `dput`, instead of an image.  Also, please tell us what you've tried so far: what have you found by Googling, and why didn't that meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

The lubridate package is very helpful for working with dates and times in R.

```
# load.packages("lubridate") ## only run once
library(lubridate)
df$Occurence_Date <- ymd(df$Occurence_Date)  # converts text in year month day format, igrores time
```

Generally it's better to put example data in your question so people can work with it and show an example.